# Running ng xi18n to generate messages.xlf on angular library throws error

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-library

I have a library component and I want to add internationalization feature to it. 
Therefore my html looks as follows for the tag I want internationalization to be applied.

```
<div><span i18n="site header|Application version@@AppVersion" class="appversion">Version: {{version}}</span></div>
```

I have added the extract-i18n tag to the angular.json for my project(angular library)[part of angular json configuration corresponding to project(tile library)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciF2i.png)

When I try to run ng xi18n tile           [tile is my angular library name],
it throws an error as follows:
[Error on running ng xi18n tile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cw4o.png).

I already tried debuggin the libraries and it seems that common.js under 'angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs' is needing in its buildOptions Output Path, but when I add output path to angular.json as in screenshot, error is thrown(this error means that the option is invalid). [Error after adding outputPath in the options for the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Sq9.png).

Can anyone tell me how can this be fixed or are there any additional settings in the configs that I need to apply internationalization to angular libraries?

Additional info:
[ng-version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqR5l.png)
I am able to run the internationalization on my angular main project but not able to on the my libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem before but from your question, I dont know why you `run xi18n tile`.
u should just run `ng xi18n`

Comment: I am running my main application and I want to build internationalization for library separately. If I run just ng i18n (from my root folder of the library), even then it picks up the root for my main application instead of the library(tile). 
Also the syntactically, I wrote tile referrring below : 
https://angular.io/cli/xi18n

Are there any settings that I need to do for it to take tile automatically.